# woocommerce: how display discount in custom loop

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to integrate my own theme with `woocommerce` and use the custom loop to display carousel of recents products. so I don't know how to display discount percentage and sale badge separately

I am running `xampp` server

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 12 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 

<div class="pdp-promo-name" itemprop="name">
    -40% 
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a full code example. The code you've posted above has an open loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to **functions.php**

```
function display_discount_percentage() {
   global $product;
   if ( ! $product->is_on_sale() ) return;
   if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
      $max_percentage = ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100;
   } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
      $max_percentage = 0;
      foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
         $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );
         $price = $variation->get_regular_price();
         $sale = $variation->get_sale_price();
         if ( $price != 0 && ! empty( $sale ) ) $percentage = ( $price - $sale ) / $price * 100;
         if ( $percentage > $max_percentage ) {
            $max_percentage = $percentage;
         }
      }
   }
   if ( $max_percentage > 0 ) echo '<div class="pdp-promo-name" itemprop="name">-' . round($max_percentage) . '%</div>'; 
}
```

and call the **display_discount_percentage()** function in your loop.

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark the answer so other people will easily find it.